# openwrt buildroot build_dir and staging_dir

Tags: openwrt

I am confused about `build_dir` and `staging_dir` in openwrt buildroot.
What are they used for?

There are `feeds` in openwrt. I would imagine to build an image. You will select the packages you want in `menuconfig` and use `make` to build it.

The packages are fetched from `feeds` and then compiled into `build_dir`?

Then what is `staging_dir` used for?

Comment: Very good question and Answers. +1

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The directory `build_dir` is used to unpack all the source archives and to compile them in.

The directory `staging_dir` is used to "install" all the compiled programs into, ready either for use in building further packages, or for preparing the firmware image.

There are three areas under `build_dir`:

- `build_dir/host`, for compiling all the tools that run on the host computer (OpenWRT builds its own version of `sed` and many other tools from source). This area will be use for compiling  programs that run only on your host.
- `build_dir/toolchain...`  for compiling the cross-C compiler and C standard library components that will be used to build the packages. This area will be use for compiling  programs that run only on your host (the cross C compiler, for example) and also, libraries designed to run on the target that are linked to - e.g. uClibc, libm, pthreads, etc.
- `build_dir/target...`  for compiling the actual packages, and the Linux kernel, for the target system

Under staging, there are also three areas:

- `staging_dir/host` is a mini Linux root with its own `bin/`, `lib/`, etc. that the host tools are installed into; the rest of the build system then prefixes its PATH with directories in this area
- `staging_dir/toolchain...` is a mini Linux root with its own `bin/`, `lib/`, etc that contains the cross C compiler used to build the rest of the firmware. You can actually use that to compile simple C programs outside of OpenWRT that can be loaded onto the firmware.  The C compiler might be something like: `staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc`. You can see the version of the CPU, the C library and gcc encoded into it; this allows multiple targets to be built in the same area concurrently.
- `staging_dir/target.../root-...` contains 'installed' versions of each target package again arranged with `bin/`, `lib/`, this will become the actual root directory that with some tweaking will get zipped up into the firmware image, something like `root-ar71xx`.  There are some other files in `staging_dir/target...` primarily used for generating the packages and development packages, etc.

Sorry its a bit verbose, this is hard to describe more succinctly.

Comment: it would be extremely useful to mention also corresponding Makefile variables for each type of the path. thanks

Comment: Thank you for explanation. If you don't mind I just copied your answer to OpenWrt Wiki https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/build-system/start#difference_between_build_dir_and_staging_dir

this may be a violation of your copyright so please just revert or edit my change

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev I don't mind, but please attribute / link back to this answer...